# lite accordion how to make full with and responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am using jquery plugin for make tab effect but we are facing issue to make tab responsive and 100% width issue.

HTML :-

```
<div id="big-tab">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h2><span>Who We Are</span></h2>
      <div>
        <h3>This is Slide One.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
          magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. <a href="#">Link somewhere</a> </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2><span>Vision and Mission</span></h2>
      <div>
        <h3>This is Slide Two.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
          magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. <br />
          <a href="#">Link somewhere</a> </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2><span>Our History</span></h2>
      <div>
        <h3>This is Slide Three.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
          magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. <a href="#">Link somewhere</a> </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

full code below link

here is [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_negi/yt11sm1z/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make responsive: true inside defaults

Comment: oky, thanks i got it, but 100% width issue? and also height go small

Comment: Try css to customize.